# How to get current user details logged through OAuth io

Tags: servlets, oauth

I am trying to create a webpage on which user can log in through google and twitter.
I have decided to use OAuth.io and I am successful configuring OAuth.io for google.
After successful logging, I redirect the user to the TestServlet.
I am not sure how to get user details once the control reaches to servlet.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use OAuth.callback in pair with OAuth.redirect (if that is what you are using) in your javascript.

You can either get your user details from client side or server side.

e.g.

```
OAuth.redirect('google', "/test");
```

and in /test:

```
OAuth.callback('facebook', function(err, result) {
  // the oauth token is in result.access_token
  result.get("/oauth2/v1/userinfo", function(data) { // or /plus/v1/people/me
    alert('Hello ' + data.displayName)
  });
});
```

if you are planning to do the api call from server-side, in java, you can pass the token (or code) to your server and either use the google java api (building a GoogleCredential) or direct http calls