# How does one integrate oauth.io into appery.io?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am developing a simple mobile app on appery.io for learning / experimental purposes at this point in time.  I would love to be able to authenticate users by integrating oauth.io to assist with this.

The oauth.io documentation is written in such a manner that it looks like it should be very simple to do but I'm hitting a dead end and I'm concerned that I'm not doing things correctly or that what I'm setting out to do is impossible.

I am following the documentation provided at the references, below.  I've installed the oauth.js file into the JavaScript folder under the project tab on appery's app builder.  I confirmed that the HTML code is set (actually, appery.io does this automatically, but I double-checked), and then the next bit of code the documentation suggests triggers an error when I set it to run on "page show" in my app's start screen.

The line

```
OAuth.initialize('key-goes-here');
```

triggers an error in the console.log as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'initialize'
```

the following line that the documentation provides also raises the same error:

```
OAuth.redirect('stackoverflow', '/auth/callback');
```

I've scoured Google, appery.io and oauth.io for answers on how to proceed with this but cannot find anything (they seem to be somewhat new services).  I don't think that this falls under appery's purview to assist me and haven't heard a reply from oauth.io.  At this point, I do not even know if it is possible to do what I'm trying to do or whether it's just me doing something embarrassingly wrong.

If anyone is familiar with both of these services and could explain how to allow for o-authentication of users using oauth.io on appery.io in terms that someone at the lower-intermediate level could understand, that would be wonderful.  Have I missed out any important information needed to assist with this?

**References:**
https://oauth.io/docs/api

[How to get current user details logged through OAuth io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889618/how-to-get-current-user-details-logged-through-oauth-io)

infoq. com/news/2013/08/oauth-io

oauth. io/auth/download/latest/oauth.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great detailed tutorial how to use oauth.io and Appery.io - http://docs.appery.io/tutorials/connect-with-api-providers-using-oauth-io/
Feel free to contact Appery.io support team via forum - https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/